# Is there a way to send body in Http Get Method in browser?

Tags: ajax, http, get

I am currently facing a requirement that could support HTTP Get Request with payload. Also this question has confused me for a long time. Is there a way to send body with a **HTTP GET request** from **browser side**? I know you could send get request with body by using Python, Php,cUrl etcs, but how about from browser side?

I have done some investigations on this topic and find out that most of the popular http request libaries such as `axios`,`request`,`superagent` do not support this feature. Even, the `fetch` and `XMLHTTPrequest` does not support Get method with payload.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)
The weird thing is that the standard(or RFCs) did not forbid sending a get request with body.
Here comes my question, is there any way from web browser we could support http get request with body?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas I have read through this post before. It does not solve my problem. Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send. It explicitly set request body to null if it is a GET. As `XMLHttprequest` is the low-level implementation for sending request. If this is not possible, how could I send out get with body from browser.